# send a DSN (Non-delivery report) using the python email module

Tags: python, python-3.x, email

I'm trying to send a DSN (Delivery Status Notification, also known as a Non-Delivery Report) from python3 using the email module.

A DSN is a MIME message with `Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status`

The messages contain 2 attachments (and an optional 3rd):

1. `content-type: text/plain` a human readable report
2. `content-type: message/delivery-status` a machine readable report
3. `content-type: message/rfc822` optionally the original message

```
#
# Get data from msg
#
headers = Parser(policy=default).parsestr(msg)
recipient = headers['to'].addresses[0].addr_spec
domain = headers['to'].addresses[0].domain
date = email.utils.formatdate(localtime=True)

#
# Create a new email message
#
dsn = EmailMessage()
dsn.policy = policy.SMTP  # <-- this didn't help
dsn.make_mixed()

dsn['From'] = headers['to']
dsn['Date'] = email.utils.localtime(dt=None)
dsn['Message-Id'] = email.utils.make_msgid(idstring=None, domain=None)
dsn['Subject'] = 'Returned Mail: Refused'
dsn['To'] = headers['return-path']

#
# The human readable part
#
dsn.add_attachment("""\
   ----- The following address had delivery problems -----
   <{}> (unrecoverable error: Refused)
""".format(recipient).encode(),
                   maintype="text",
                   subtype="plain",
                   cte=None)

#
# The machine readable part
#
dsn.add_attachment("""\
Reporting-MTA: dns; {}

Original-Recipient: rfc822;{}
Final-Recipient: rfc822;{}
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.1
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 571 Delivery not authorized, message returned
Last-Attempt-Date: {}
""".format(domain, recipient, recipient, date).encode('us-ascii'),
                   maintype="message",           # <--- these 2 lines cause
                   subtype="delivery-status",    # <--- the issue
                   cte=None)

#
# The original message
#
dsn.add_attachment(msg.encode(),
                   maintype="message",
                   subtype="rfc822",
                   cte=None)

#
# Set the Content-Type header in the message headers
#
dsn.replace_header('Content-Type', 'multipart/report')
dsn.set_param('report-type', 'delivery-status')

print(dsn)  # <--- Dies in here
```

When the DSN is printed, I receive the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./send-dsn.py", line 97, in <module>
    print(dsn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/email/message.py", line 971, in __str__
    return self.as_string(policy=self.policy.clone(utf8=True))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/email/message.py", line 968, in as_string
    return super().as_string(unixfrom, maxheaderlen, policy)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/email/message.py", line 158, in as_string
    g.flatten(self, unixfrom=unixfrom)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/email/generator.py", line 116, in flatten
    self._write(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/email/generator.py", line 181, in _write
    self._dispatch(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/email/generator.py", line 218, in _dispatch
    meth(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/email/generator.py", line 276, in _handle_multipart
    g.flatten(part, unixfrom=False, linesep=self._NL)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/email/generator.py", line 116, in flatten
    self._write(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/email/generator.py", line 181, in _write
    self._dispatch(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/email/generator.py", line 218, in _dispatch
    meth(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/email/generator.py", line 335, in _handle_message_delivery_status
    g.flatten(part, unixfrom=False, linesep=self._NL)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/email/generator.py", line 107, in flatten
    old_msg_policy = msg.policy
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'policy'
```

The problem seems to be the maintype and subtype of the second attachment, the `content-type: message/delivery-status` attachment.  If I change this to `text/plain`, the DSN prints except that the second attachment has the wrong content-type.

1. Is this the correct way to build a DSN using this module?
2. How can I fix this policy attribute problem?

Comment: I tried to play around with this code, but I can't really figure it out. It seems like you might have found a bug in the attachment code. Maybe you'll just have to generate `msg.as_string()` and then substitute the content type for the delivery report within that, though that's a horrible workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this too, and it took a bit of figuring out. I'm sure I'll need to refer back to this answer some day...

As @tripleee points out, this uses the older API. However I wasn't able to acheive this with the new `EmailMessage` API without hacky workarounds, so it's the best "proper" solution I have for the moment until the newer API matures.

```py
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.message import MIMEMessage
from email.message import Message


# Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status
msg = MIMEMultipart('report', report_type= "delivery-status")

msg['Subject'] = 'Delivery Status Notification (Failure)'
msg['From'] = 'Mail Delivery Subsystem <mailer-daemon@example.com>'
msg['To'] = 'address@example.net'

msg.attach(MIMEText("Human readable explanation. Mailbox unavailable.", 'plain'))

# message/delivery-status - machine readable rfc3464 report
delivery_status = """
Reporting-MTA: dns; {}

Original-Recipient: rfc822;{}
Final-Recipient: rfc822;{}
Action: failed
Status: 5.5.0
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable
Last-Attempt-Date: {}
"""

dsn = Message()
dsn.set_payload(delivery_status)
msg.attach(MIMEMessage(dsn, 'delivery-status'))

# message/rfc822 - optionally the original message
original = Message()
original.set_payload("the original message, or a portion thereof, as an entity of type message/rfc822")
msg.attach(MIMEMessage(original, 'rfc822'))

print(msg)

server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_host, smtp_port)
server.sendmail('', msg['To'], msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

Comment: As an aside, it looks like your `email` code was written for an older Python version. The `email` module in the standard library was overhauled in Python 3.6 to be more logical, versatile, and succinct; new code should target the (no longer very) new `EmailMessage` API. Probably throw away this code and start over with modern code from [the Python `email` examples documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)

Comment: Thanks @tripleee. I couldn't find a way of making it work with the `EmailMessage` API, at least not without hacky workarounds - do you have a better example?

Comment: My answer contains my best attempt, but it is indeed hacky. What I'm saying is, if you recommend falling back to the legacy API, warts and bugs and all, perhaps your answer should be more explicit about that.

Comment: Fair enough @tripleee, I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the handling of the `message` main type is incomplete or buggy.

A complication is that `set_content` and `add_attachment` behave differently depending on whether you are attaching a `str` or a `bytes` object. I guess you already figured this out, but it can be somewhat puzzling.

`cte=None` in your code seems to be motivated by similar observations. If you put `cte="7bit"` then Python will again try to convert the object into a string, which it can't if it's already a `bytes` object.

The best I can come up with is a brute-force touch-up to replace the content type after rendering the message.

```
import email.utils
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.parser import Parser
from email.policy import default

msg = """\
Return-Path: <sender@example.org>
From: me <sender@example.org>
To: recipient <victim@example.net>
Subject: Deliver this

Hello
"""

#
# Get data from msg
#
headers = Parser(policy=default).parsestr(msg)
recipient = headers['to'].addresses[0].addr_spec
domain = headers['to'].addresses[0].domain
date = email.utils.formatdate(localtime=True)

#
# Create a new email message
#
dsn = EmailMessage()
# dsn.make_mixed()

dsn['From'] = headers['to']
dsn['Date'] = email.utils.localtime(dt=None)
dsn['Message-Id'] = email.utils.make_msgid(idstring=None, domain=None)
dsn['Subject'] = 'Returned Mail: Refused'
dsn['To'] = headers['return-path']

#
# The human readable part
#
dsn.set_content("""\
   ----- The following address had delivery problems -----
   <{}> (unrecoverable error: Refused)
""".format(recipient))

#
# The machine readable part
#
dsn.add_attachment("""\
Reporting-MTA: dns; {}

Original-Recipient: rfc822;{}
Final-Recipient: rfc822;{}
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.1
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 571 Delivery not authorized, message returned
Last-Attempt-Date: {}
""".format(domain, recipient, recipient, date).encode(),
                   maintype="application",
                   subtype="x-tripleeee-message-delivery-status",
                   cte="8bit")

#
# The original message
#
dsn.add_attachment(msg.encode(),
                   maintype="message",
                   subtype="rfc822",
                   cte="8bit")

#
# Set the Content-Type header in the message headers
#
dsn.replace_header('Content-Type', 'multipart/report')
dsn.set_param('report-type', 'delivery-status')

#
# Touch up CTEs
#
parts = list(dsn.iter_attachments())
parts[-1].replace_header("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "7bit")
parts[-2].replace_header("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "7bit")

#
# Now here's the really fugly part
#

# parts[-2].replace_header("Content-Type", "message/delivery-status")
as_bytes = dsn.as_bytes().replace(
    b"application/x-tripleeee-message-delivery-status",
    b"message/delivery-status")

print(as_bytes.decode())
```